# Get expire time of OAuth session

Tags: c#, oauth, owin, asp.net-web-api2

To grant or revoke access to my webapis, I use OAuth password- and tokenrefreshworkflow.

If I understand everything correctly the workflow should be something like this:

1. Authenticate with username / password / client id
2. Retrieve accestoken, refreshtoken and expire date
3. Start timeout in client to refresh your token after expired token time
4. Go on with bullet 2 -> and so on..

The progress above works fine so far. My problem is, that I don't get the expire time out of the users principle after the authentication request. So if I work with stateles webclients, I need to renew my token every request to retrieve a new expire date, even if the users token is valid :/

What I want is something like a /api/session/information service, that provides general information about the current session of an authenticated user.

How do I retrieve my expire date =)

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("information")]
public HttpResponseMessage Information(BaseRequest request)
{

    var p = Request.GetRequestContext().Principal;

    /* here i need help =) */
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your access token (JWT?) should contain an expiry claim. In JWT it is "exp", which shows the number of seconds since 1970-1-1. In javascript you can get a date from this like this:

```
new Date(<exp> * 1000);
```

In .Net / C# you would be able to do the same:

```
var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
return epoch.AddSeconds(<exp>);
```

Is that what you are looking for? Otherwise let me know. Happy to help :-)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly henrik, I need to store the expiry date in a claim and calc the time difs by hand? There is no way Oauth is telling me, how long my token is valid?

Comment: Yes, in most applications consuming OAuth2 tokens the EXP is required. So if you have access to your token, you know how long it lives. Since the token is the only authentication/authorization you normally send to an endpoint, this info must be present, but you could also return at as a "bonus info" to the client requesting the token. Sort of "Expires in 20 minutes".

Comment: For server side I can very much recommend the JWTSecurityTokenHandler from Microsoft (NuGet).

Answer (score 18):

Just to expand on Henrik N.'s answer a little. If you're in C# then you can use `JWTSecurityTokenHandler` within `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` (Nuget: `Install-Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`) to read the token and the resulting `JwtSecurityToken` object gives you some handy properties, one of which is `ValidTo` which converts the `exp` claim into a `DateTime` object for you E.g.:

```
var tokenString = GetTokenString(); // Arbitrary method to get the token
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var token = handler.ReadToken(tokenString) as JwtSecurityToken;
var tokenExpiryDate = token.ValidTo;

// If there is no valid `exp` claim then `ValidTo` returns DateTime.MinValue
if(tokenExpiryDate == DateTime.MinValue) throw new Exception("Could not get exp claim from token");

// If the token is in the past then you can't use it
if(tokenExpiryDate < DateTime.UtcNow) throw new Exception($"Token expired on: {tokenExpiryDate}");

// Token is valid
```

Comment: is it possible to read the token's expiry date without its secret?

Comment: FYI, in version 6.7.1 of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, we may call handler.ReadJwtToken(tokenString) without the need to cast to JwtSecurityToken.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds:

```
   var jwtExpValue = long.Parse(principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "exp").Value);
   DateTime expirationTime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(jwtExpValue).DateTime;
```