# Proper way to get an Azure AD Access Token expiration date

Tags: c#, .net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

Based on [Get expire time of OAuth session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829879/get-expire-time-of-oauth-session) I create a simple method to retreive expiration date. I used both of answers and get different results:

```
        var tokenResponse = await httpClient.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = tokenEndpoint,
            ClientId = client,
            ClientSecret = secret,
            GrantType = "client_credentials",

            Scope = scope,
        });


        var currDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        var tokenExpireDate1 = currDateTime.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn);


        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jwtToken = handler.ReadToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken) as JwtSecurityToken;
        var tokenExpireDate2 = jwtToken.ValidTo;
```

Why dates are different? And why second date is less then current date?

Comment: By how much do they differ? Did you take timezones into account?

Comment: Keep in mind that internally, JWT always keeps expiring data as UTC. You can view it easily by JWT token browsers like https://jwt.ms/ or https://jwt.ms/
`tokenResponse.ExpiresIn` is MS identity based, as docs said "How long the access token is valid (in seconds)."

Comment: Instead of adding seconds in `DateTime.Now`, you can use `DateTime.UtcNow` and then check both dates it will show the same date or accurate result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` is the time in the system's local time zone while `jwtToken.ValidTo` is the UTC time.

Just convert the tokenExpireDate1 to UTC time you will find the two date are the same.

```
DateTime tokenExpireDate11 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(tokenExpireDate1);
```